# Function abs() returning negative number in C

Tags: c, absolute

I was doing some test with my program, and I found that the abs function returns a negative value with a specific value. You can check it yourself with this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    long number = abs(2147483648);
    printf("%ld",number);
}
```

And the result is:

```
-2147483648
```

Why happen this? I know that number is the max_int+1, but I don't understand the internal logic of this.

Comment: IMHO internal logic is implementation dependent. It's just undefined behaviour as far as programmer is concerned

Comment: The abs, labs, and llabs functions compute the absolute value of an integer j. If the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Comment: Consider in the future reading the documentation before asking the question. For example, if you are using the MSVC compiler you could read the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw1ee768.aspx which clearly describes precisely the behaviour you're experiencing. As it states **the abs functions cannot be used to guarantee a positive value.**

Comment: It is amazing that all of us explain why it happens, but nobody says that it was a problem of an API. Such kind of problems can be simply resolved if to use, for example, following: **unsigned** int abs(int);

Answer (score 5):

Recall that the absolute value function returns the magnitude of a number. Also recall that integer representations of **signed** numbers are done in two's complement notation, where the GSB (greatest significant bit) is the signed digit, halving the positive integer range of that interpretation.

You're passing the absolute value function a signed int number, to which it returns a number which is then interpreted to be a signed long number from an int. If you were to make that long a unsigned long, and use `labs` instead of `abs`, the result would be positive.

What happened is an integer overflow from casting a signed interpretation of an int, which returns a signed interpretation of an int, which is then casted to a long.

Answer (score 2):

On your system `2147483648` literal cannot fit in an `int` so its type is either `long` or `long long`. When the literal is passed to the `abs` function, the argument is converted to `int` and the result of the conversion is `INT_MIN`. `abs(INT_MIN)` is not representable in an `int` (`-INT_MIN` is an integer overflow in two's complement systems) and invokes undefined behavior (`abs` specifications says that *If the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined.*)

Answer (score 0):

`abs` expects `int`. You are passing a number which is out of range of `int` which causes integer overflow.